# Function input not recognised - local & global environment issue

Tags: r, function, dplyr, environment

I am writing a function to group together actions I regularly take on time series data. I have included all libraries I am using in the script as I think my issue may be to do with plyr / dplyr being (rightly) super specific about the environment of each variable.

The first function works great, but when getting to the second one, R doesn't recognise the input as 'x', but spits out the error: 'Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x' not found.'

Why is this happening?

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(xts)
library(forecast)
library(imputeTS)
library(lubridate)

x1 = arima.sim(list(order = c(0,1,0)), n = 119)

timetrend <- function(x, starts, ends, frequency) { 
  y <- list()
  y[[1]] <- ts(x, start = starts, end = ends, frequency = frequency)
  y[[2]] <- decompose(y[[1]])
  y[[3]] <- y[[1]] - y[[2]]$seasonal - y[[2]]$random
  return(y)
}

plottime <- function(x) { #takes a timetrend list as input
  t <- tslm(x[[3]] ~ trend)
  plot(x[[3]])
  lines(t$fitted.values)
  return(t)
}
```

## use functions from here

```
result <- timetrend(x = x1,
                  starts = c(2000, 01, 01), ends = c(2009, 12, 01), frequency = 12)


plottime(x = result)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look - this piece of code works fine for me and result gets created.

Comment: My system reports that `decompose` is from the igraph package. So I now get the same results and result as you did when I use `stats::decompose`

Comment: When you indexed the `result`-object, it removed the second element of `result` which is where the `$trend` item is stored. Look at `str(result)` and the code for `tslm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could make it work with the following code.

```
plottime <- function(x) { #takes a timetrend list as input
  y=x[[3]]
  t <- tslm(formula = y ~ trend)
  plot(x[[3]])
  lines(t$fitted.values)
  return(t)
}
```

[image]

Not sure why it is happening, maybe the use of indexing x[[3]] in the formula argument is a problem?

Comment: Thanks - yes when I took out the indexing it worked fine. Would be great to know what is causing the error. Thanks.